How Do I Remove the Center Binding from a Scanned Book Image?
I recently found this book titled "Genetics and Evolution" by Jill Bailey. There is a 'knowledge map' in the book but it is divided by the book's center binding (see image here for reference). I'd like to scan this and get this printed as a poster. However, I have no idea how to get it into one flat image. Any help would be appreciated!

You can't flatten that out well.
To have any chance of having something remotely fixable, you need to break the book. Break the binding so the pages can lie flat when scanning. If you can get a flat scan, without the binding, for each page then you may be able to address the seam that would be between the two pages. it appears the be hard cover and perfect bound, so you'd really need to damage the book to break the binding. If you aren't willing to damage the book, then your are just in for a very uphill struggle.
The effort required to minimize, much less remove, the shadows and distortion due to the gutter would be well below the effort to merely recreate the image. I have no idea what your software proficiency may be. Even if you are "whiz" with Photoshop, it's not an easy task to "fix" a scan of that.
Recreate the image - it'll be  a much better use of time with better end results.
Have you considered copyrights. It's an infringement to create a poster from published works. If you were to create the poster yourself, then print it yourself, to display on your own wall, then it's fine. However, if anyone else creates the poster, or you pay someone to print the poster they would be profiting off the intellectual property of the publisher and would be infringing upon copyrights. There's a reason you can't easily get posters made of anything you see published.
In other words, do it all yourself and it's probably "fair use". Have someone else do any part of the process and it may not be.
